# jquery selecting all elements except the last per group

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a table that looks like:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>one</td><td>two</td><td>three</td><td>last</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>blue</td><td>red</td><td>green</td><td>last</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Monday</td><td>Tuesday</td><td>Wednesday</td><td>last</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

What I want is a jquery selector that will choose all but the last `td` of each table row. I tried:

```
$("tr td:not(:last)").css("background-color","red");
  //changing color just as a test...
```

But instead of all cells but the last on each row being changed, all cells but the very last one in the table are selected. Similarly, if I change it to:

```
$("tr td:last").css("background-color","red");
```

the only one that changes is the very last cell. How do I choose the last (or not last) of each row?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('tr td:not(:last-child)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

It's saying each `<td>` that's not the last in that particular `<tr>`

Comment: I'm not sure this will work in my case, but maybe you can tell me for sure. I simplified my html for the sake of the question, but each td has other elements inside, such as inputs and labels. Will the `last-child` look for descendants as well, or just the first-level children?

Comment: Just the td, since there's no space in the selector means the `:` operators apply to that same element, in this case the `<td>`.  So just first-level chidren, if you have a table with nested td's, change the selector to be `tr>td:not(:last-child)`, this ensures only the first child of whatever table/tr you're on.

Comment: Thanks @Nick! This cleared up a major piece of jQuery functionality I am writing!!

Answer (score 16):

```
$('tr').find('td:not(:last)').css('background-color', 'red');
```

Translates to: for each element in `$('tr')` selector, do a `find()` for all `td`s that are not last.
New result is about `td`s now, so you can apply `.css()` as wanted.