# Help with JQuery selector :not(:last)

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to select all the bullets except the last bullet but I am doing something incorrectly.

Here is my html

```
<ul>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
</ul>


<ul>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
<li>Text</li>
</ul>
```

And my jQuery:

```
jQuery('ul li:not(:last)').append(" | ");
```

It's adding the pipe to every bullet however...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? It works completely fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/qmVdb/

Comment: Except the very last `li`, or except the last `li` of *each `ul`*?

Comment: Yeah I realized I was trying to do the last li of EACH ul...

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401109/jquery-selecting-all-elements-except-the-last-per-group

Comment: Performance-wise it's actually faster to use an array `.splice(array.length - 1, 1)` on `$('ul li')` than to use `:not(:last)`. It doesn't look as nice though.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Because your html contains multiple unordered lists, `$('ul li')` will selects every single `<li>`, in all of the `<ul>`s. [`:last`](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) then selects the final element in that list. Use [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/), which gets the last `<li>` in *each* of the `<ul>`s.

```
$('ul li:not(:last-child)').append(' | ');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/qmVdb/1/

Comment: Since my use was a bit different (I was using it with removeClass), I needed just a single element so I went with last as opposed to last-child, but your code snip was super helpful.  Thanks! 
$('.active:not(:last)').removeClass('active');