# Fire Click Function except for the last <td> element - Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have this table in a php document

```
    <?php
    echo "
    <table id='supplier-detail-table' class='table table-responsive table-hover'>
            <tr><th>Supplier Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Phone</th><th>Fax</th><th>Email</th><th>Website</th></tr>";
                foreach ($all_suppliers as $supplier){
                    echo "<tr data-id=".$supplier['id']."><td class='text-center'>".$supplier['name']."</td><td>".$supplier['address']."</td><td>".$supplier['phone']."</td><td>".$supplier['fax']."</td><td>".$supplier['email']."</td><td><a href='".$supplier['url']."' target='_blank'>".$supplier['url']."</td></tr>"; 
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

I want the table rows to be clickable so that when a row with a particular `data-id` is clicked, the user is taken to the full details of the supplier

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#supplier-detail-table tr").click(function(){
        if($(this).data("id")){
            window.location="http://localhost/nams/index.php/View/Supplier/"+$(this).data("id");
        }
    })
});
```

Now as you can see the user is taken to the full-detail page about the supplier if the row is clicked.

But the last `td` element, I have placed it as `<a></a>`. Therefore when the user clicks on the website, a blank tab with the url is loaded, also the current page is changed to the full detail page.

How can I prevent this from happening?

If the user clicks on the `td:last-child`, the click function should not work! so that the blank page opens and this page should not load to full-detail page.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5640968/2962442

Comment: But I need entire `<tr>` to be clickable except the last `<td>` .. If I use `<td>` to make it clickable, the spaces between `<td>` will not be clickable

Comment: It's not my downvote.

Comment: Do you think this deserves a downvote?

Comment: In my opinion no, but I'm just a user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$("table tr")
.on("click", function(e) {
  if ($(this).is("tr:last")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false
  };

  // do stuff
});
```

```js
$("table tr")
.on("click", function(e) {

  if ($(this).is("tr:last")) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false
  }
  
  console.log($(this).text())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>a</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>b</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>c</td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28796309/fire-click-function-except-for-the-last-td-element-jquery/">123</a></td>
  </tr>
  </table>
```

Comment: this makes entire tr be not clickable

Comment: What am trying to do is make entire `<tr>` clickable except the last `<td>`