# Select all checkbox except the last of a specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I want to check if all checkbox of a specific element are checked BUT the last one
I have this kind of HTML

```
<ul class="progress-indicator">
  <li>
    //Others elements (variable)
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox"> // Exclude this one
  </li>
  <li>
    //Stuff here
  </li>
  <li>
    //Another stuff
  </li>
</ul>
```

I firstly tried that

```
if($(".progress-indicator > li:first-child").find(":checkbox").length == $(".progress-indicator > li:first-child").find(":checkbox:checked").length)
{
   //All checkbox of first li are checked
}
```

This is working but now I want to exclude the last checkbox of the first `li`

So I started with that

```
$(".progress-indicator > li:first-child").find(":checkbox:not(:last-child)").length
```

But it did not work. This selector select only the first checkbox of the first `li`. I think it due to the `Others elements` that I have before. (The checkbox are by exemple inside a `div` which is inside another element.

So, how to select all the checkbox of the first `li` except the last checkbox **OF** this `li` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jquery selecting all elements except the last per group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2401109/jquery-selecting-all-elements-except-the-last-per-group)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do,

```
var last = $(".progress-indicator >li:first-child").find(":checkbox:last");
```

So your statement will be

```
if($(".progress-indicator > li:first-child").find(":checkbox").not(last).length == $(".progress-indicator > li:first-child").find(":checkbox:checked").not(last).length)
{
  //All checkbox of first li are checked, regardless of the last one
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**eq**](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) with a negative number & [**not**](https://api.jquery.com/not/) selector to omit the last element

```
var x=$("input:checkbox").not(":eq(-1)");
x.each(function(){ // this part just for demo
$(this).prop("checked",true)
})
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/6Lgwykx1/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use jQuery's each function to iterate through the checkboxes. I would exclude the last one.

Something like this:

```js
$checkboxes = $('.checkbox')
lengthCheckboxes = $checkboxes.length;

$checkboxes.each(function(i,e) {
 if (i !== lengthCheckboxes - 1) 
  $(e).prop( "checked", true );
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
    //Others elements (variable)
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox"> // Exclude this one
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

This shall do the trick.

```
$('.progress-indicator input[type="checkbox"]').not(':last-child').each(function(){
    $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

Kind regards.